# Two same instances created with page refresh in moodle

Tags: javascript, ajax, moodle

I am calling an ajax function from a moodle block when a onchange event is detected. It sends courseid to server page and returns the necessary fields which updates a div inside a block. The dropdown which has the onchange event is also generated by a database call. Now the problem is, when I am adding that block in a moodle page, the page get refreshed and I see two instances of that block. What could be the reason?

**Update**

The structure of my code was as following;

```
<script></script> 

<?php




 ?>
```

From inside the php block I was calling a javascript function with some parameters. It was changing a div of the php block. The javascript was sending those parameters to another php page where I wrote the db queries. Now when I changed the code to following, the error was gone:

```
 <?php

   script was written inside $this->content->text

 ?>
```

Can you shed some light on what could be the reason?

Comment: It's probably caused by a logical error somewhere in your code.

Comment: This was the most useless comment I ever got, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps my sarcasm was too understated.  That is the best answer you can get without more information.  The odd behavior describe is most likely because a bug in your code, code which you did not post.  There could be a million reasons why you are getting this unexpected result.  You just asked a mechanic to fix your car without ever showing them the engine.  So pop the hood, post the relevant code and you may get more helpful replies.